# Silverlight - Serialize Partial Class with a custom method

Tags: c#, silverlight, serialization

I have a Silverlight app I've been working on. This app relies on a custom class called `Customer`. Instances of this class are returned from my web service. I've need to add a method called `CalculateLoyalty()` to this class definition. I want `CalculateLoyalty` to be available on both the server and client-side (my Silverlight app).

Currently, I can use `CalculateLoyalty` just fine on the server. Unfortunately, the method doesn't seem to get passed across the wire. I have a hunch its some serialization thing. How do I add a method to my class definition on the server-side and ensure that it is available on the client-side?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sharing the `Customer` class file between your service and your client or are you using the class generated by adding a service reference on your client?

Comment: I'm using the class generated by adding a service reference on the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you generate a service reference, it only copies public properties and fields.  You can share classes between your server and client and avoid using a service reference.  I'm not going to go into detail with how to do this, but here are some related questions that explain what needs to be done.

[Create WCF Client without auto generated proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8361646/create-wcf-client-without-auto-generated-proxy)
[Call synchronous WCF operation contract methods asynchronously on silverlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7648249/call-synchronous-wcf-operation-contract-methods-asynchronously-on-silverlight)

Even if you do this, I have to recommend against putting logic on your DTOs.  I'd recommend creating a `LoyaltyCalculator` class and passing a `Customer` to this.  In fact, you can do this even if you use generate your client through the **Add Service Reference** option.

Your defult Silverlight solution will have 2 projects.

- MyApp - This is your Silverlight project.
- MyApp.Web - This is the host web project.

You don't need to do this, but I recommend adding 2 new projects.

- MyApp.Shared - A .NET Class Library
- MyApp.Shared.Silverlight - A Silverlight Class Library.

At this point, you will want to add a project reference to the appropriate class library to both your Silverlight project and your Web project.

Add class `LoyaltyCalculator` to `MpApp.Shared`, or `MyApp.Web` if you don't want to make the shared libraries.  Go ahead and implement this class here.

Now in `MyApp.Shared.Silverlight`, or `MyApp` if you don't want to make the shared libraries, select *Add -> Existing Item*.  Browse to and select `LoyaltyCalculator.cs`.  **Do Not Double Click It!!!**  Instead, click the little down / more arrow on the Add button.  Now select *Add As Link*.

`LoyaltyCalculator` is now available to both your server and client and you only have to maintain one copy.

Answer (score 0):

Methods are not serialized, only data (property/field values) are, so you must be using a different version of the .cs file on the server than you are on the client.  Are you sharing the source code between your web service and silverlight projects?

If you are on .NET 4.5/VS2012, you may be able to create a "Portable class library" with your class in it that can be referenced from both your .NET and Silverlight projects.